# How can I test my SQLite database via script in a Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, scripting

On the Rails console my Class User looks like this:

```
irb(main):005:0> User
=> User(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I can generate an instance of User using

```
irb(main):006:0> User.create(:name => "user0")
```

What I want to do is test my database by creating a number X of instances of User. I thought about writing a Ruby script in which I cycle through a loop - something like (not real Ruby code!)

```
for i in 1..X do
  User.create(:name => "name"+i)
end
```

But I don't know how to access my Class in Ruby and how to "tell" the console to generate actual objects.

Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here.  The best option is to learn how to write unit tests, either using Rails's default [Test::Unit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), or [RSpec](http://rspec.info/), or some other alternative.  This is the right way, and in fact Rails comes all wired up with tests by default.  You've got a `test` directory, and `rake test` and other testing tasks.  If you use Rails generators (`rails g model Foo`), it'll even create the test files for you.  You just need to fill them out.

If you're not ready to learn the testing frameworks, then you can put your code above into a file (let's call it `test_user.rb`) and run it through `rails runner`.  That will bootstrap the Rails environment before executing your code, and you'll have access to the model:

```
rails runner test_user.rb
```

Comment: thanks jim! learning the testing framework is number one on my todo-list but i'm on a tight schedule tonight. let me see if i can get the second option to work

Comment: wow this actually works (i'm surprised because i do a lot of c programming and ruby and ror is really straight forward) - thanks a lot!:-)

Comment: Glad it helped.  I see you're new here.  If you're satisfied with the answer, please click the check-mark to the left of it to accept.  Feel free to wait and accept an alternate answer as well.  Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create some seed data for your database. Why not run your code in Rails console directly? Or you could create a Rake task, and run the seeding from there.

I would also recommend using [Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/), this will give you some real-looking data:

```ruby
require 'faker'

for i in 1..X do
    u = User.new
    u.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
    u.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
    u.email = Faker::Internet.email
    u.notes = Faker::Lorem.paragraph
    u.cell_phone = Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone
    u.home_phone = Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    u.save
end
```